Ubuntu software updater unable to install libssl3 package
Im trying to get a lab enviroment ubuntu up and running with vsftpd and some task scheduel tasks.
Im in need of a web browser aswell but it seems like something is corrupt or not working properly on the machine. Im trying to see if i can resolve it with a software update, but im unable to excecute all of it as im getting stuck on the installation of libssl3. Its stuck att setting up fase and i cant get around it, i thought ill make an installation download with wget and install from the machine but not working either. I tried also to install a diffrent web browser(chrome) instead but then im having issues with dkpg conplaining as below.
waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is heWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 2664 (aptd)
i also get a matching fault on dkpg aswell with process 2283.
I would be happy if someone could narrow down the problem and find a workaround to get everything properly running.
I might need to a consistency check on the OS or restore but im quite new to the linux world so i could need some help here.
Thank you in advance

Sounds like update is running in the background, let it finish,then run upgrade,then try your libssl3.
